# Can I put a link in a bootstrap popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to do something like this:

```
  $('.UofTennesseeKnox').popover({
    'selector': '',
    'placement': 'bottom',
    'title': '<a href="home.html">University of Tennessee-Knoxville</a>',
    'content': 'Facilities Services Department 2233 Volunteer Boulevard, Room 203 Knoxville, TN 37996-3010',
  });
```

but the whole value of 'title' appears on the page, including the tags. Is there an easy way to do this, or do I need to use a different popover script?

Answer (score 5):

```
      $('.UofTennesseeKnox').popover({
        'selector': '',
        'placement': 'bottom',
        'title': '<a href="home.html">University of Tennessee-Knoxville</a>',
        'content': 'Facilities Services Department 2233 Volunteer Boulevard, Room 203 Knoxville, TN 37996-3010',
        'html': 'true'
      });
```

Duh.....

Comment: Please don't bother. I found the issue was in missing to wire my popover after insertion into my html page. Thanks.